# How to display email avatar in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, gravatar, avatar

I want to display email's user avatar in my web site.
I used `gravatar.com` component before to do this. But some of my users don't have an account in that site and i decide to display them email's avatar for example when they comment under a post, i wanna to display this avatar.
I Google it, but i can't find a nice answer. can everybody guide me about this?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What do you mean by "email's avatar"?

Comment: @nunespascal, yeah, exactly

Comment: I was asking you to explain what is this email's avatar, and where it comes from? gravatar allows you to configure the image to show if your user is not there on their list.

Comment: @nunespascal: OK,i know power of gravatar. but in many  web sites i see my idea! 
even i test this matter. when i leave a comment under their posts i write one of my email that never register in gravatar.com! but i see my email avatar in that comment! Now i want to implement this idea in my web site.